# Striptime unconverted data remains

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a new list from information that I'm getting from a JSON file but I'm getting this:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
unconverted data remains: 9+01:00
  File "C:\Users\2913843\Desktop\VS code\Random Projects\Test Folder\datetest.py", line 7, in <lambda>
    newlst = sorted(data,key=lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x['startTime'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'),reverse=True)
  File "C:\Users\2913843\Desktop\VS code\Random Projects\Test Folder\datetest.py", line 7, in main
    newlst = sorted(data,key=lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x['startTime'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'),reverse=True)
  File "C:\Users\2913843\Desktop\VS code\Random Projects\Test Folder\datetest.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
```

The time format in the JSON is:

```json
"startTime":"2023-03-20T07:26:37.5000623+00:00"
```

and the line in the code for the new list is:

```py
newlst = sorted(data,key=lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x['startTime'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'),reverse=True)
```

My desired output would be in this format:

```
2023-03-30 19:25:13.822945
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It would be very helpful if you provide desired input and output plus a full stacktrace if possible.

Comment: thank you i edited my first post, hopefully that info helps

Comment: Use Python 3.11, where `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()` works with this format and was updated to ignore the extra digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the [table of format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), you will see that `%f` is:

> Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded to 6 digits.

So you are trying to format a string with a format specification that doesn't handle all the characters.

---

You have a few options. Here are 3:

```py
from copy import deepcopy
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

data = [
    {"startTime": "2023-03-20T07:26:37.5000623+00:00"},
    {"startTime": "2023-03-19T06:02:12.1231233+00:00"},
]

FMT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"


def a(data: list[dict]) -> list[dict]:
    new = deepcopy(data)
    for d in new:
        d["startTime"] = datetime.strptime(
            d["startTime"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f3%z"
        ).strftime(FMT)
    return new


def b(data: list[dict]) -> list[dict]:
    new = deepcopy(data)
    for d in new:
        d["startTime"] = parser.parse(d["startTime"], fuzzy=True).strftime(FMT)
    return new


def c(data: list[dict]) -> list[dict]:
    new = deepcopy(data)
    for d in new:
        d["startTime"] = datetime.strptime(
            d["startTime"][:26], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"
        ).strftime(FMT)
    return new


def d(data: list[dict]) -> list[dict]:
    new = deepcopy(data)
    for d in new:
        d["startTime"] = datetime.fromisoformat(d["startTime"]).strftime(FMT)
    return new


print(sorted(a(data), key=lambda d: d["startTime"]))
print(sorted(b(data), key=lambda d: d["startTime"]))
print(sorted(c(data), key=lambda d: d["startTime"]))
print(sorted(d(data), key=lambda d: d["startTime"]))
```

Which yields:

```
[{'startTime': '2023-03-19 06:02:12.123123'}, {'startTime': '2023-03-20 07:26:37.500062'}]
[{'startTime': '2023-03-19 06:02:12.123123'}, {'startTime': '2023-03-20 07:26:37.500062'}]
[{'startTime': '2023-03-19 06:02:12.123123'}, {'startTime': '2023-03-20 07:26:37.500062'}]
[{'startTime': '2023-03-19 06:02:12.123123'}, {'startTime': '2023-03-20 07:26:37.500062'}]
```

### a

The first option adds, a random "3" into the format string, which is no good. Basically, it has to match whatever the 7th millisecond position is, so it will fail 9 of 10 times on average.

### b

In option b, the string is being parsed using a fuzzy feature in [dateutil.parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse).

### c

Lastly, if the precision isn't required, you can just truncate the first 26 digits and use a more simple format string.

### d

As Mark noted in the comments above `fromisoformat` will work in Python 3.11+.

---

*note: These functions all use `deepcopy` which is probably not efficient and I don't know your use case. You should just update in place, if you don't need both the old and new lists.*

Also, I'm not sure I recommend using a static format string like this. Usually it is optimal to stick with `date.isoformat()` or formatting based on locale with `%c`.

Comment: pretty much but like i said im not sure how to get around it

Comment: Thank you, this has help a lot

Comment: I just realized you were seeking actual reformatting, not just sorting. So, this may help but is incomplete.

Comment: Its given me a good jumping off point

Comment: @Faubad It has been updated accordingly. Good luck.